# How can I verify the reliability/integrity of a DVD?

Tags: dvd, verification

I am looking for a way to verify DVD media for reliability. The media in question can be a commercially available movie or game. Basically I want to check if the media is in playable condition.

I understand that there may not be a solution which does it 100% accurately, since certain brand of players are more fussy about the media it can play than others. I am ok if the solution catches, say 90% of all the bad ones.

PS: I don't want to verify blank DVD media onto which data has been written. I am interested only in commercially available, factory pressed DVDs.

Oh and speed is of great importance.

Answer (score 2):

You can only verify the data on a disk if you have a reference, valid disk, or preferably, the original disc image used to create the disk.  This is why it's preferred at burn-time to use the burning tool's built-in validation after burning (because some CD/DVD media do have intrinsic defects).

Unless you have the **original disc image**, *or* the checksums of the files were generated and stored with the files on the disc, it would be impossible to validate the integrity of the data (and think about it, if you don't know what those 0's and 1's *should* be, how could you?)

One thing that you *can* test for is physically corrupted media which presents read errors to the actual CD/DVD drive.  For that, you can use a disc imaging tool which supports error checking.  However, note that this will only validate the integrity of the disc itself, and not the contents of the files.

---

In terms of software, you might want to look at the [Nero CD-DVD Tool](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/Nero-CD-DVD-Speed) (free) or [Opti Drive Control](http://www.cdspeed2000.com/) (free 30 day trial), but there are several other tools which can do this.  Should you try the Nero tool, [this article](http://www.digitalfaq.com/guides/media/dvd-tests.htm) outlines the process using the Nero CD-DVD Speed tool (see the section titled *Test #3 - Surface Scan Test*).  Finally, note that many programs to rip CD/DVDs to the hard drive will also check for read errors.

Comment: Do you know of a hardware solution that can do the latter?

Comment: Any recommended software tools?

Comment: @BobbyAlexander in terms of a hardware solution, none that I know of that I would consider to be consumer-available (I'd expect disc duplication devices might be able to, but they can be expensive).  Also, I've updated the answer with some example software tools you could use to verify the sectors on a disc.

Answer (score 1):

I use VSO Inspector for DVD movie error checking:

http://www.vso-software.fr/products/inspector/inspector.php

Comment: Just saying you use this tool isn't a great solution to what was asked.  For all we know, you could be a masochist and use this because it is the worst tool.  Please expand your answer to explain what makes it a good tool.  Even better, provide at least a sense of how you use it to solve the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: This isn't open source, and worse yet, only runs on Windows.